# changing element.style on the finishing position of a jQuery animated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

I am using a photo album jQuery plugin (Supersized). It includes a thumbnail tray which slides up from the bottom of the screen at the touch of a button, resulting in the following HTML being created onto the div properties and in firebug css 'element.style. property:

```
style="display: block; bottom: -150px;"
```

and when caller clicked:

```
style="display: block; bottom: 0px;"
```

I am trying to place a footer div at the bottom of the page though, so want to move the finishing position to 'bottom:0px'. I have seen that an extra element.style can be added to local CSS but without a 'before' and 'after' type of selection I don't understand if that can help me. Furthermore I don't find the function in the JS files and from what I understand it can't be accessed anyway. I need to change these to be:

```
style="display: block; bottom: -150px;"
```

and when caller clicked:

```
style="display: block; bottom: 42px;"
```

Any advice would be most welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickedElement').on('click', function() {    
    $('#element').css('bottom', '42px')
});
```

If i didn't missunderstand you?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the function which you can not find is jquery `.css()` function you can read how it works [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Also if you want to animate some dive you can use jquery `.animate()` function ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)).

In your case it should looks like:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#element').animate({
        $('#element').css('bottom', '42px');
    }, 5000, function() {
    });
});
```

Where `5000` it's time of your animation in miliseconds.

Comment: Thanks Mateusz, in the end it was hidden in here: $(vars.thumb_tray).stop().animate({bottom : 0, avoidTransforms : true}, 300 );